# Как положить переменную в дженерик-тип?

Tags: java, generics

Такой код не работает:

```
public static <T> void doSomething(Class clazz) {
    List<clazz> list = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Как можно положить в `generic`-тип переменную ?

Comment: Никак. Обобщения существуют только на этапе компиляции, а переменные получают свои значения в рантайме.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev справедливо)

Comment: Почему нельзя написать `List<Class> list` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обычно это делается так:

```
public static <T> void doSomething(Class<T> clazz) {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ещё можно передать не класс, а представителя:

```
public static <T> void doSomething(T t)
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Создать объект нужного класса можно с помощью `reflection`.